# WPF: Most efficient way to remove the last item from a bound list?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, binding, processing-efficiency

In a WPF application, I've a list of object.

We will add a lot of element inside this list regularly(~1-10 items/seconds).

We want to add a "capacity" to this list, in order that when we reach this capacity, we remove the "oldest" item added.

This list will be bound to a WPF UserControl, so it needs to be `ObservableCollection` or similar.

But, my understanding is that a `Collection` doesn't garantee the order, so I cannot do the following:

```
int nbOfElementsToRemove = EventsList.Count - MAX_EVENTS;
if (nbOfElementsToRemove > 0)
{
    LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents = EventsList.Take(nbOfElementsToRemove).ToArray();
    foreach (LoggingEvent loggingEvent in loggingEvents)
    {
        EventsList.Remove(loggingEvent);
    }
}
```

Because I will maybe not get the oldest items.

So what is the most efficient way of removing the oldest item(s) of a list that has to be bound to a WPF usercontrol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` is indeed an ordered collection, so you should have no problem removing the oldest one through a variety of means.

If you're simply adding items through `EventsList.Add()` then you can remove the first item in the collection: `EventsList.RemoveAt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The ObservableCollection is ordered so you will be fine removing it using the index.